# Tricking the JVM into casting arrays

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I'd like to know is there is a way to cast an array of `SuperType` into and array of `SubType`. Like so:

```
SubType[] subArray = (SubType[])someSuperTypeArray;
```

I know that at runtime this throws a `ClassCastException`. A way to convert an array would be to copy it into another array. In my case, copying it is not an option.

Can I trick the JVM into beliving that the cast is valid, and bypass class type checks? Creating a reference to the array of `SuperType`, through which it is seen as some `SubType` array. (Possibly facing the dangers of unexplainable errors)

Comment: What does "I away to convert an array would be to copy it into another array" mean?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my end.

Comment: No tricks - take the long way.  Instantiate a new array of the type you want, iterate over the superclass, and cast each reference as you assign it.

Comment: As far as I know, even if there was a way to cast an array to an array of different type, the complexity would be O(n), because Java would need to check each element's type to determine whether it should throw a ClassCastException. To avoid hiding an O(n) operation in a cast (which is usually O(1)), Java doesn't allow you to cast arrays at all. Allowing a cast that bypasses type checks would remove the whole point of type checks in the first place.

Comment: Yep :( It seems that tricking the JVM into beliving that a some object is actually another type, would mean breaking stuff and having a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you define the array like

```
SuperType[] array = {element1, element2};
SubType[] array2 = (SubType[]) array;
```

it will not work, however you can do this:

```
SuperType[] array = new SubType[]{element1, element2};
SubType[] array2 = (SubType[]) array;
```

You just have to make sure that the field `array` always has to be an array of your SubType when you're casting it.

Comment: I might be missing the point, but why do you want to cast something which is already the type of the 'new' variable. You are basically creating a pointer in my mind

Comment: @engineercoding To access members that are not present in `SuperType`?

Comment: @engineercoding well, if you have a method that takes a SubType[] as parameter, e.g. void method(SubType[] array){} and you want to put in your SuperType[], it needs to be created like this.

Comment: Well maybe it is in a framework, where you can have an arbitrary amount of classes extending a particular class of the framework. And you can tell the framework "hey, would you make a 2D array where I can store references to my subclasses", then "please give me a reference to a particular 1D array which contains all of my classes of a particular subtype, for fast retrieval, but make it so I don't have to cast each one into a subtype of my desiere". (In my particular case :D)

Answer (score 1):

There are only two possible array instances that `someSuperTypeArray` can point to.

1. `SuperType someSuperTypeArray = new SuperType[10];` : You can add `SuperType` objects or `SubType` objects to  this array
2. `SuperType someSuperTypeArray = new SubType[10];` : You can only add `SubType` objects to this array. (Technically, you can add `SuperType` objects to this array at compile time but this will result in an `ArrayStoreException` at runtime)

Let's assume for a second that in case 1, you do manage to trick the JVM into allowing you to cast the `someSuperTypeArray` reference to a `SubType[]` reference. What should be done if `someSuperTypeArray` has an element of type `SuperType`?  You can't really expect the cast to implicitly discard all `SuperType` elements.

In case 2, is there any point of using a `SuperType[]` reference to a `SubType[]` array instance if all you want to do is cast the reference to a `SubType[]` reference. Just use a `SubType[]` reference in the first place.

Comment: Well in the first case it seems that "Congratulations! I've managed to expose a security vulnerablity in some JVM". I was not aware of the second case, thank you for pointing it out. Somehow I didn't think of actually trying it out.